# MS Word - How to view detailed modifications in content control

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm using Word 2010.

I create a raw text content control.
I change the properties of the content control to allow carriage return.
I add some text to this content control.
I right-click and accept insertion.
I show markups.
Now if I modify the content all the previous text is striked out.
I was waiting that only modified text was in red for easing track changes.

This is an example of result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQQHg.jpg). I just added "ed" to the verbs but all text has been striked out.

Is it possible to configure it ?
I think this problem is not specific to Word 2010 as a colleague uses Office 365 and he has the same problem.

Comment: https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/word2010/reviewing-documents/1/

Comment: This problem is specific to content control. Track changes is working as expected on normal text. I want the same behavior for text inside a content control.

Comment: Does this issue occur with Rich Text Control Content? I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: I tested with raw text. This issue does not occur with Rich Text Control Content.
Actually, I uses an application generating a raw text control so I cannot event replace it by a Rich Text Control Content but I can tell to the app developer to use a Rich Text Control content instead of a Raw Text Control content.
Your answer really helped me. Thank you!